# Is it possible and how could it possible for plant to survive in naked space

Tags: plant-physiology, extremophiles

I heard that there are fungi could survive on space station in the naked space. I want to know if any plant could be able to do the same

How many limitation of plant differ from fungi

And could it possible for them really grow with photosynthesis from the sun. At least growing out of space station which we may fed them with our carbon and water but not limited to only inside of our shell

Comment: Do you have a link to show that fungi can live in naked space?  
From what I know, the space fungi are all living inside the space stations.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Sorry but I remember it wrong, it is lichen https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/06/120623145623.htm